# Linking two tables in MYSQL. The other table can be null

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am working on a project with NODE JS and MYSQL. I want to implement a ban system. It works like this, an admin will warn the user which will be stored in the warnings table with fields (warningsId,userId,reason) and if the admin has warned the user 3 times already, the user will be banned it will be stored in ban table with fields (ban_id, userId,dateStart,dateEnd,reason). In ban_faculty table the fields are (userId, total_ban, isBanned) in the isBanned field if its 0-2 the user is just warned, if it goes up to 3 the user is banned. However, I can't find a way to link warnings table and ban table, because the ban table can be null while the warnings can't.

I want them to be linked for example if the user is banned, I can check the reasons in 0-2 warnings.

Example:

```
"warnings"
warningsId -0
userId - 3
reason - "Lel"

"ban_faculty"
userId - 3
total_ban - 5
isBanned - 1    

"warnings_ban"
warningsId -0
ban - NULL
?????????????????????

"ban"
ban_id - 1
ban_facultyId  - 3
dateStart - 2018-01-01 05:55:31
dateEnd - 2018-04-03 06:15:21
reason - "lol"
```

Comment: So `isBanned=2` means that the user is not banned. Your future self will curse you for this. ;-)

Comment: Can't find another way man. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks for the response :))

Comment: Apart from that, it sound like you 'just' need a left join, but I'm have some trouble figuring out exactly what you need. Part of your problem (apart from the naming I mentioned), is that you seem to be storing aggregate data. So you got some warnings in a table, but you also got is_banned in the other table, with sounds to me like a count of warnings. My first question would be: Do you really need to store that count, or can you rely on counting the individual warnings? Could be a case of premature optimization, and as a consequence maybe you're having a hard time figuring out where to look.

Comment: What do you want?Do you want the banned user warning details then you need to do inner join on ban and warning table

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)